# ->probe() function is not called while loading the Linux kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

This is my first time writing a Linux kernel driver. After looking for examples online, I started to write my driver. The driver is getting initialized but the `->probe()` function is not revoked. I have attached below my C code and the relevant device tree node code snippets.

Can you please help and let me know what changes should I make?

DTS file:

```dts
ubv@96002000 {
    compatible = "ubv";
    no-map;
    reg = <0 0x96002000 0 0x0002000>;
};
```

Driver C code:

```c
static int ubv_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
        printk (KERN_ALERT "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
        pr_info("---------------%s\n", __func__);
        return 0;
}

static int ubv_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
        pr_info("------------------- %s\n", __func__);
        return 0;
}

static struct of_device_id ubv_match_table[] = {
    { .compatible = "ubv" },
    {}
};

static struct platform_device_id ubv_plat_device_ids[] = {
    { .name = "ubv" },
    {}
};

static struct platform_driver ubv_platform_driver = {
        .probe = ubv_probe,
        .remove = ubv_remove,
        .id_table = ubv_plat_device_ids,
        .driver = {
                .name = "ubv",
                .owner = THIS_MODULE,
                .of_match_table = ubv_match_table,
        },
};

static int __init ubv_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    printk (KERN_ALERT "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);

    ret = platform_driver_probe(&ubv_platform_driver, ubv_probe);
    printk (KERN_ALERT "ret = %d\n", ret);
    pr_info("ret = %d\n", ret);

    return ret;
}

static void __exit ubv_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&ubv_platform_driver);
}

module_init(ubv_init);
module_exit(ubv_exit);
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `ret = platform_driver_probe(&ubv_platform_driver, ubv_probe);` with `ret = platform_driver_register(&ubv_platform_driver);`?

Comment: I would suggest dropping these module `->init()` and `->exit()` callbacks and just use `module_platform_driver(ubv_platform_driver);` instead. @IanAbbott

Comment: @0andriy I tried with your advice. I cant see the printk statement on the terminal. But I can see the driver is made inside the below path

[root@abk]# find /sys | grep "ubv"
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ubv
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ubv/uevent
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ubv/bind
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ubv/unbind
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/reserved-memory/ubv@96002000
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/reserved-memory/ubv@96002000/compatible
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/reserved-memory/ubv@96002000/reg
/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/reserved-memory/ubv@96002000/no-map

Comment: If you want your driver to be probed automatically, you need to add `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, ubv_match_table);`. Otherwise you need to do it manually.

Comment: `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` allows the user-space uevent handler to load the module automatically when the device is detected, but does not otherwise affect operation of the driver.

Comment: Regarding `module_platform_driver(ubv_platform_driver)`, that will not be suitable if the module needs to register anything else besides the platform driver (such as a device class, a character device number region, etc.). @0andriy

Comment: Unless you have a special requirement, you probably don't need to fill in the `.id_table`. Filling in the `.of_match_table` should be sufficient. I haven't checked, but maybe using the same `"ubv"` string in the `.id_table` and the `.of_match_table` is confusing things. Also, most OF compatible strings have a `vendor,` prefix. On second thoughts, `platform_match()` in "drivers/base/platform.c" will try to match against the `.of_match_table` (if `CONFIG_OF` is enabled) before it tries to match against the `.id_table`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I made the changes with platform_driver_register command and in that i can see ubv_init and ret=0 in the terminal and the same structure as described above when i use the find command. Is my driver active now ?

Comment: @0andriy I added the MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE command, no significant change is observed. Nothing on the terminal and I can find the driver using the find command under the described path as mentioned before.

Comment: @IanAbbott   If i write some data say "1234" inside the probe function. Can i see this command inside the driver ? If yes, can you please tell the necessary changes i need to do. For eg. if i do cat ubv inside the driver my output = 1234

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Sorry, I've no idea what you are going on about in your last comment.

Comment: I think you might have added your `ubv@96002000` node as a child of the `reserved-memory` node. If that is the case then the node will not be probed by your device driver because reserved memory child nodes do not have device drivers.

Comment: @IanAbbott .. Your advice made a great change.  Yes it was a child node of a reserved-memory and now i have moved it out of reserved-memory. I can see the probe function  in the terminal now and the driver been created. Thanks !

Comment: @IanAbbott I want to transfer some data at this memory ubv@96002000 and display it on the terminal. What and Where should i write my function ? Can you please help or should i make a separate question for it ?

Comment: @IanAbbott, perhaps you should copy your comment into an answer so that Abhishek Pandey could mark it as accepted.

Comment: "*Yes it was a child node of a reserved-memory*" -- This post is a good example of the failure to provide proper context for the DT node can hinder a solution.  The DT is a *tree* with a hierarchy; it is not just a *list*.  The parent(s) of a node can be salient information, and should be provided with the node itself.